# WCF + Silverlight + HttpContext.Current.Session is null

Tags: silverlight, wcf, session, basichttpbinding

my problem....

i am tryingo to access session from Silverlight and WCF basicHttpBinding...

i saw some posts where it's possible (http://www.dotnetspider.com/Silverlight-Tutorial-317.aspx)

Mys cenario is:

Silvelright 4 FW 3.5

in web.config i have

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ViewModelDemo.Web.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ViewModelDemo.Web.Service1Behavior" name="ViewModelDemo.Web.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ViewModelDemo.Web.Service1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and my service:

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class Service1
{
    [OperationContract]
    publicvoid Test()
    {
        var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
    }
}
```

and it''s call

```
                var client = new Service1Client();
                client.GetUserMacroFunctionsCompleted += new System.EventHandler<GetUserMacroFunctionsCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetUserMacroFunctionsCompleted);
                client.GetUserMacroFunctionsAsync();


void client_GetUserMacroFunctionsCompleted(object sender, GetUserMacroFunctionsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var test =  ((Collection<Function>)e.Result);
    }
```

HttpContext.Current is always null!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Yes HttpContext must be always null because your service configuration doesn't setup ASP.NET compatibility and your service doesn't require ASP.NET compatibility.

Add this to your configuration:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

And change `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements` so that your service cannot be hosted without former configuration:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This link probably to help you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sajay/archive/2006/08/03/687361.aspx

`aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"` doesn't help me till I set `allowCookies="true"` on the client binding configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Update your web.config file to include

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    
</system.serviceModel>
```

This should work, or else also change the AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode attribute on the contract to Required.